# Seeing through high-res wireframes

Tags: modeling, wireframe

Sometimes when working with high density meshes (like sculpting in multires, which is my case) in wireframe mode, there are so many edges that I can barely see through the model, making it very hard to check background images and objects behind it.

[image]

Is there a way to work with a simplified wireframe or is there some other see-through mode I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Background image panel (N in the viewport), you can choose to have the background image in Front, instead of Back, and set the opacity level

Comment: nice, thanks! i would never think about that